# Using PUT and DELETE methods in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-post, http-delete, http-put

I'm trying to use `RequestMethod.PUT` and `RequestMethod.DELETE` in Spring MVC controller (version 3.0.2). There are three methods mapped with a URL in the Spring controller class as follows (PUT, GET and POST respectively, for the demonstration purpose only).

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.PUT}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"}, headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
public String update(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") TempBean tempBean, BindingResult error, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    }

    System.out.println("Request method PUT");
    return "admin_side/Temp";
}

@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"})
public String showForm(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") TempBean tempBean, BindingResult error, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Request method GET");
    return "admin_side/Temp";
}

@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.POST}, value = {"admin_side/Temp"})
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("tempBean") TempBean tempBean, BindingResult error, Map model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Request method POST");
    return "admin_side/Temp";
}
```

When the page is loaded, the the `GET` method is invoked as obvious but in all other cases (when the page is submitted), the only method to be invoked is `POST`, the method designated with `RequestMethod.PUT` is never invoked.

---

The Spring form contains only a submit button and an image browser as,

```
<form:form id="mainForm"
           name="mainForm"
           method="PUT"
           action="Temp.htm"
           enctype="multipart/form-data"
           commandName="tempBean">

    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

The generated HTML is as follows,

```
<form id="mainForm"
      name="mainForm"
      action="Temp.htm"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>
    <!--This hidden field is implicitly included-->

    <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile"/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In my `spring-config.xml` (`dispatcher-servlet.xml` in my case), I have added a reference to [`CommonsMultipartResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html):

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

and in my `web.xml` file, [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) is configured as follows,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>multipartResolverBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>filterMultipartResolver</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

The `PUT` (and `DELETE` too) method is never invoked (with no exception or error). What am I missing here?

---

**Update :**

With the following configuration in `web.xml`,

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param> <!-- Makes no difference, if excluded. -->
        <param-name>multipartResolverBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>filterMultipartResolver</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  <!--Changed from /* to dispatcher-->
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> <!--Changed from /* to dispatcher-->
</filter-mapping>
```

**it throws the following exception.**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'filterMultipartResolver' is defined

Where the name `dispatcher` is the name of the Servlet - `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` already mapped in web.xml as follows.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm not sure what else is needed? Is the filter [`HiddenHttpMethodFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) required to implement on our own extending [`OncePerRequestFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) something like the one shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/parancoe/source/browse/parancoe-web/src/main/java/org/parancoe/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java?r=8d63b047e8218191390ffedb1b70e3f9ddc626c3)? (it is a built-in class)

Important points are listed [here](http://dev.anyframejava.org/docs.en/anyframe/plugin/springrest/1.0.2/reference/html/ch08.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most browsers do not support `action=PUT` in HTML forms. They will just send `POST` requests instead. The [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) will help you get around the problem, but you have to include a hidden field `_method=PUT` in your form. If you use the spring:form taglib this will be done automatically for you, but your example seems to use plain HTML.

The `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is most probably an unrelated problem.

Comment: I'm using that tag library - `<form:form>...</form:form>` and the hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT"/>` is automatically included in **the generated HTML** as shown in the second and third code snippets in the question. I have already seen so many posts on this site as well as other tutorials. I'm almost doing as described by them though the thing doesn't work, in my case. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Your text, "*The NoSuchBeanDefinitionException is most probably an unrelated problem*" is correct. The only problem was that I had misconfigured this `org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver` and placed in a wrong xml file instead of placing it in  `applicationContext.xml`. Hence, it was causing the exception. It now works and the method designated with `RequestMethod.PUT` in the Spring controller is invoked. One problem still remains is that `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)` always returns false. It returns true only on `POST`. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Difficult to guess ... first thing that comes to mind: are you sure that your PUT request is a multipart request (I know, dumb question, but sometimes the aswer is obvious).

Comment: No problem, I will post this as a new question. By the way, yes it is a multipart request with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and   `method="put"`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your config.

```
<servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
```

to

```
<servlet-name>[dispatch servlet name]</servlet-name>
```