# Delete or put methods in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to call `@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)` in spring from thymeleaf form.

Is there any possibility to call delete or put request mapping methods from thymeleaf?

please give your suggestion on this.

Answer (score 33):

You could use `th:method` for this:

```
<form th:object="${commandObject}" th:action="@{/urlToCall}" th:method="delete">
```

This will generate a hidden input element, which will be picked up by Spring MVC:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
```

Comment: For me I had to add `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true`to my `application.properties` file to work.

Answer (score 18):

When we use `th:method="PUT"`, thymeleaf creates hidden input as in the screenshot below. Then **HiddenHttpMethodFilter** converts posted method parameters into HTTP methods.

[image: httpmethodfilter-conversion]

HiddenHttpMethodFilter [disabled](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#httphiddenmethodfilter-disabled-by-default) by default in Spring Boot 2.2.

You can enable this by adding `spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true` to your application.properties file.

Comment: the best answer

Comment: I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: Really the best answer

Answer (score 10):

Thymeleaf is an HTML template engine. HTML does not support `put` or `delete` HTTP methods for its `method` attribute. So, no, you can't. However, you have alternatives.

You can use javascript to send the request asynchronously. In that case, you can send any type of HTTP request.

You can also use a `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` with a `hidden` `_method=put` `<input>` element as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629653/using-put-and-delete-methods-in-spring-mvc). Something like

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Only solution I've found - use js:

Add scrypt:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    function sendDelete(url) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("DELETE", url, true);
        xhttp.onload = function () {
            let responseURL = xhttp.responseURL;
            console.log("Redirecting to:", responseURL);
            window.location.replace(responseURL);
        };
        xhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

and add calling link (or change to button):

```
<a type="button" th:with="url = @{<your_url>}" th:onclick="sendDelete([[${url}]])">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use it and it works well.:

try this instead:

spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled=true

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing research on this subject. As far as I understand, we can perform these operations without the need to use `PUT` or `DELETE` methods. So you may not need to use JavaScript or anything else. These operations can be done using only Thymeleaf, HTML and Spring.

If someone has come here for this and is looking for such a solution, please check the post at this address. It was useful for me.

Here's link: [Spring Boot CRUD Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf)