# Where can I see the specification for thymeleaf th:method?

Tags: thymeleaf

I've seen a lot of answers about how to send PUT/DELETE/PATCH HTTP requests with thymeleaf, and it's by using `th:method = "the_specific_method"`, but i haven't found the thymeleaf specification about that. Can anyone help showing me where is it?

Thanks in advance.

I've tried to google for the answer, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`th:method` isn't special to Thymeleaf -- it's just like any other plain old attribute which will output the result of an expression to the `method` attribute.  It doesn't do (or care about) anything else.  You can put any string and/or string expression into it, and Thymeleaf will happily output it.

```
th:method="${'the_specific_method'}"
```

will output

```
method="the_specific_method"
```

without regards to whether or not it's valid.  If you want to learn about the `method` attribute, you just need to learn about how method works in [plain old regular html](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) and how browsers (and/or Spring) work with it.

Comment: But, as far as I know, in plain old regular html, only GET and PUT methods are valid... Am I wrong? And, on the other hand, while searching for this, I've come to answers like https://stackoverflow.com/a/24753505/11315401 that means translation is not so simple, what I'm missing?

Comment: No, that is correct, `GET` and `POST` are the only valid methods.  There is no translation in Thymeleaf. Thymeleaf doesn't care what you put in `th:method` -- the answers you've linked to are using a *Spring* filter to fake different methods by modifying the output of certain properties -- and while Thymeleaf gives support for hooking into their tag library, additional `th:method` logic isn't something specifically built into Thymeleaf.  If you want to learn about that, you need to learn about the HiddenHttpMethodFilter and not `th:method`.